# Placing an IFrame before the Silverlight object in aspx page fails to render the Silverlight Control

Tags: html, silverlight, iframe

I'd like to have an IFrame appear above my Silverlight control (top to bottom not Z-Order).

If I place the IFrame element before teh Form element only the IFrame appears on my screen.

To reproduce create a new Silverlight 3.0 Web Application.  In you TestPage.aspx simply add:

`<iframe width="600" height="200" src="http://www.google.com" />`

before the lines

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:50%">
    <div id="silverlightControlHost">
        <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
```

My complete body tag reads as such...

```
<body>
<iframe width="600" height="200" src="http://www.google.com" />    
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:50%">
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
<param name="source" value="ClientBin/SilverlightAndIFrame.xap"/>
<param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
<param name="background" value="white" />
<param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40818.0" />
<param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
<a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=3.0.40818.0" style="text-decoration:none">
  <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
</a>
 </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
</form>
```

Sadly only the IFrame appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iframes require closing tags (closing with `/>` doesn't work) try:-

```
 <iframe width="600" height="200" src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony.  Stupid HTML ;)